# A series of radial gauge controls in a Reporting services report

Tags: reporting-services

I have the following sql:

```
SELECT 
    project_title + ' (' + pack_type + ')' AS label
    , ordered
    , received
FROM [v_stock_and_despatch] ORDER BY [order]
```

that returns the following table:

```
label    ordered received
Item A   60      76
Item B   63320   63960
Item C   415240  415226
Item D   23150   23150
Item E   147948  187992
```

Now, in Reporting services I need to show this as a sequence of radial gauges.

I know how to create a one off guage, but I don't know how to create a collection.

The value field for a one off guage looks like this:

```
=Fields!received.Value /(Fields!ordered.Value) * 100
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table for your data details, and drag a Gauge item into one of the cells. Your existing expression should work for the gauge's value. The table will give you a row for each of your projects, and the gauge on each row will use the Received and Ordered values for that project.

[image: table with radial gauges]

In my example I've switched the column labels for Received and Ordered, so the values appear as less than 100%.

The same technique will work with Chart items.